# EF CF - Get Child Table Information without foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a question about EF code-first.

I created two POCO classes and corresponding mapping classes

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        this.States = new HashSet<State>();
    }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}

internal partial class Country_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public Country_Mapping()
    {                        
          this.HasKey(t => t.CountryId);        
          this.ToTable("Country");
          this.Property(t => t.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId");
          this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(100);
          this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(200);
          this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
     }
}

public partial class State
{
    public State()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

internal partial class State_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<State>
{
    public State_Mapping()
    {                        
          this.HasKey(t => t.StateId);        
          this.ToTable("State");
          this.Property(t => t.StateId).HasColumnName("StateId");
          this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(100);
          this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description").IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(200);
          this.Property(t => t.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId");
          this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
          this.HasOptional(t => t.Country).WithMany(t => t.States).HasForeignKey(d => d.CountryId);
     }
}
```

In the `Country` and `State` classes, there is no navigation relation from `Country` to `State`.
But now I want to get all states of that country using the `Include` statement of Entity Framework .

```
UnityOfWork work = new UnityOfWork(new DbContextFactory<eSMSDbContext>());
var countryColl = work.GetRepository<Country>().Table.Include("State");
```

How can I get the states information through the country?

Answer (score 0):

Without a navigation property from the `Country` class to the `State` class, the Country objects do not have any variable to hold the contents of the `State` table.  Entity Framework is only able to map the SQL information into C# objects if they are present.

Short of adding navigation properties, you'll need a separate variable (`List<State)`, perhaps) to hold the `State` objects, and unfortunately you will need a separate Entity Framework call to look up these values, something like

```
List<State> states = work.GetRepository<State>().Where(s => s.CountryId == countryId);
```

This has the obvious drawback of being a separate object from your `Country` object, and is not nested (a `List<Country>` wouldn't be able to hold a `List<State>` corresponding to each).